# crm_resource equivalent command in pcs

Tags: pacemaker

Linux pacemaker cli crmsh (crm_resource) has a command to tell the cluster that a resource has failed.

> −F, −−fail
>
> (Advanced) Tell the cluster this resource has failed

Is there an equivalent command in another pacemaker cli **pcs** where I can inform the cluster that a resource has failed.